# Box-sizing problem when using image rotation

Tags: html, css

I have a rotating date table it works fine when I remove `box-sizing: border-box;`from style.

[image: See in image]

But when I use `box-sizing: border-box;` it looks like this :
[image: See in image]

Here is my html and css codes :

```css
.entry-inner { padding-bottom: 18px; margin-bottom: 16px;}
.date { margin-right: 15px;  position: relative; float:left; padding: 14px 12px; width: 40px; height: 34px; background: url(https://i.ibb.co/RHwTRRv/date-ico.png) no-repeat 0 0; } 
.date strong { color:#00acef; font-size: 22px; line-height: 22px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; display:block; }
.date span { font-weight: bold; font-size: 9px; color:#c6c6c6; position:relative; margin-top: 0px; display:block; line-height:9px;  }
.date em { -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); line-height: 12px; -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; width: 12px;  color:#bdbdbd; font-size: 12px; position:absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 41px; }
```

```html
<div class="entry-inner">
  <div class="date">
    <strong>
      27                            </strong>
    <span>2019</span>
    <em>Agu</em>
  </div>
  <div class="cnt">
    <p>test</p>
    <p class="meta">Author :
    <a title="paginate" href="pro">test</a> / 
    <a title="test" href="test">test</a> / Gösterim 99</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** : I changed css background height and width, it solved the problem thanks.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Question was in second image. but nvm I solved it Thanks.

Comment: Hi @meedo-man if you solved please  post the answer (or delete the question). It would be nice if you also make the question more clear by explicitly write it.